# Android Jetpack DataStore value is not null the first time the app is opened

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

When using a specific name for the DataStore ("settings" in this case), the Preference value is not null the first time I open the app. But if I change the DataStore name to something different, it will work fine. Any clue why this is happening?

Here's the broken code:

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

class SettingsDataStore @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {
    private val showPermissionDialogKey = booleanPreferencesKey("isPermissionDialogShown")

    val showPermissionDialog: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[showPermissionDialogKey] ?: true
    }

    suspend fun setPermissionDialogShown() {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[showPermissionDialogKey] = false
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the working code:

```
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "my_settings")

// Same as before ...
```

Note that I just changed the name of the DataStore from "settings" to "my_settings".

Comment: How are you determining it is not null the first time, and what value is it? Are you clearing the app data from the phone between tests?

Comment: I put a log inside _context.dataStore.data.map_ body and it returns false the first time I open the app. If I clear the app data and reopen the app, the value is finally null. The problem is that whenever I open the app for the first time, the value is not null, even after clearing the app data before reinstalling the app.

Comment: Try setting a log everywhere in your app where you actually set a value in the data store. I suspect you are setting a value before reading it for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try to log when I set the value, but it's not called when opening the app for the first time. Also, if that was the issue, it wouldn't be fixed by just changing the name of DataStore. I suspect that the name "settings" shouldn't be used at all, but it sounds weird as no documentation mentions this.